# ffmpeg hls stream to nginx webdav. Remove old segments

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, webdav

I'm trying to stream mp4 file in loop to my nginx server. And i need to remove old segments:

> ffmpeg -re -stream-loop -1 -i /data/samples/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -c copy -f hls -hls_time 5 -hls_flags delete_segments -hls_list_size 5 http://127.0.0.1:8080/upload/stream.m3u8

Everythink is ok, but when ffmpeg tries to remove old segment I've got this error in nginx:

> [error] 22#22: *73174 DELETE with body is unsupported, client:
> 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "DELETE /upload/stream16.ts HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"

My nginx config:

```
location /upload {
        root /data/live;
        dav_access user:rw group:rw all:rw;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        create_full_put_path on;
        charset utf-8;
        autoindex on;   }
```

ffmpeg 4.4.1

nginx 1.21.4

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ffmpeg http muxer that underlies the hls muxer defaults to chunked transfer encoding. When the DELETE request is made there is no body, but ffmpeg still makes the request with a single zero-length chunk.

The error message in nginx could be slightly more helpful. Indeed, it does not support webdav DELETE requests with a body, but it also does not support DELETE requests which are marked as chunked transfer encoded, regardless of whether there is a body (see: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_dav_module.c#L315), hence the error.

It looks like it should be possible to disabled this behaviour in ffmpeg using the `chunked_post` option, but it doesn't appear to be working. Not sure if this is a bug or not, or it seems like a bit of a hack anyway.